# C++: How do I make this shape from this code?

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to make this shape from the code below. I'm confused as to how to make it print the 2nd row, second to last star without it skipping and printing the extra space before printing the star. Once that is figured out would the bottom half, when the stars expands back out, would the code be similar to the top half? I have tried a couple combinations of code between c and r but I have been stuck with what I currently.

```
---------------------- //row 0
*                   *| //row 1
* *               * *| //row 2
* * *           * * *|
* * * *       * * * *|
* * * * *   * * * * *|
* * * * * * * * * * *|
* * * * *   * * * * *|
* * * *       * * * *|
* * *           * * *|
* *               * *|
*                   *|
----------------------

#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter a positive odd number less than 40: ";
    int num = 0;
    int z = 1;

    for (int a = 0; a < 3; ++a)
    {   
        cin >> num;
            if (num < 38 && num > 0 && num % 2 == 1)
            {
                cout << "Thank you!" << endl << endl;

                for (int r = 0; r < num; ++r)  //outer loop/rows
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < num; ++c)  //inner loop/columns
                    {
                        if (r == 0) cout << "--"; //top of square
                        else if (c >= r + r - c && c < num - 1)
                            cout << "  ";
                        //else if (c == num - 1) cout << "*|";
                        else if (r == num - 1) cout << "--"; //bottom of square
                        else if (c == num - 1) cout << "*|"; //right side of square
                        else if (r > c) cout << "* ";
                    }
                        cout << endl;

                }
                break;
            }
            else cout << "Please enter a positve odd number that is less than 40!" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you had to do manually, what logic would you use?

Comment: Try by creating two different loops for upper half and lower half(two loops inside one for loop(for rows) ). It would be lot easy to understand and also implementing this way.

Comment: How come the left side of the square does not have `|`?

Comment: I will try that @RajeevSingh, thank you!

Comment: @NathanOliver it wasn't needed for this project for some odd reason.

Comment: Why do you reject 39? It's a positive odd number less then 40.

Comment: Ops, thanks for catching that. Not sure why I did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just took two variables `left=0` & `right=num-1` and increased `left` & decreased `right` till `r<=num/2`, after that i reversed the process,when the `col <= left` or `col >=right` I printed `*`. 
I hope it will be easy to understand.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter a positive odd number less than 40: ";
    int num = 0;
    int z = 1;

    for (int a = 0; a < 3; ++a)
    {   
        cin >> num;
            if (num < 38 && num > 0 && num % 2 == 1)
            {
                cout << "Thank you!" << endl << endl;
                int left=0,right=num-1;

                //for printing top line
                for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) cout<<"- ";
                cout<<"-"<<endl;

                for (int r = 0; r < num; ++r)  //outer loop/rows
                {
                    //printing columns
                    for(int c = 0; c < num; c++)
                    {
                        if(c <= left || c >= right)
                            cout<<"* ";

                        else
                            cout<<"  ";
                    }
                    if(r >= num/2)  //checking for half of the rows
                    {
                        left--;right++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        left++;right--;
                    }
                    cout<<"|"<<endl;
                }
                //for printing last additional line
                for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) cout<<"- ";
                cout<<"-"<<endl;

                break;
            }
            else cout << "Please enter a positve odd number that is less than 40!" << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much! That makes perfect sense now. I have been trying to work out different statements for a few hours now and just could not get it to do what I wanted haha

Answer (score 1):

This approach does it the math way.

Furthermore it draws a full frame with plus-chars at the edges.

Give it a try.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

int main() {
  cout << "Enter a positive odd number less than 40: ";
  int num = 0;
  int z = 1;

  for (int a = 0; a < 3; ++a) {
    cin >> num;
    if (num < 40 && num > 0 && num % 2 == 1) {
      cout << "Thank you!" << endl << endl;

      int center = ceil(num / 2.0);

      for (int r = 0; r <= num+1; ++r) { //outer loop/rows
        for (int c = 0; c <= num+1; ++c) { //inner loop/columns
          if (r == 0 || r == num+1) {
            if (c == 0 || c == num+1)
              cout << "+"; // corner
            else
              //top or botton of square between corners
              if (c == center)
                cout << "-";
              else
                cout << "--";
          }
          else if (c == 0 || c == num+1) {
            cout << "|"; // left or right frame
          } else {
            // inner part
            if ((center-std::abs(center-r)) >= center-std::abs(center-c))
              if (c < center)
                cout << "* ";
              else if (c > center)
                cout << " *";
              else
                cout << "*";
            else
              if (c == center)
                cout << " ";
              else
                cout << "  ";
          }
        }
        cout << endl;
      }
    } else
      cout << "Please enter a positve odd number that is less than 40!" << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way (with some more user input checking):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

const auto ssmax = std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max();

const int max_dim = 40;
const int max_iter = 3;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter a positive odd number less than " << max_dim << ": ";
    int num = 0, counter = 0;

    while ( counter < max_iter ) {   
        cin >> num;
        if ( cin.eof() ) 
            break;
        if ( cin.fail() ) {
            cout << "Please, enter a number!\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(ssmax,'\n');
        }
        if ( num < max_dim  &&  num > 0  &&  num % 2 ) {
            cout << "Thank you!\n\n";

            //top line
            string line(num * 2, '-');
            cout << line << '\n';

            for ( int r = 0, border = num - 1; r < num; ++r ) {
                cout << '*';
                for ( int c = 1; c < num; ++c ) {
                    if ( (c > r  &&  c < border) || (c < r  &&  c > border) )
                        cout << "  ";
                    else
                        cout << " *";
                }    
                // right border
                cout << "|" << '\n';
                --border;
            }

            //bottom line
            cout << line << '\n';

            ++counter;
        } else {
            cout << "Please, enter a positive odd number that is less than 40!\n";
        }
    }
    cout << std::endl;
}
```

Or my favorite:

```
        // top line
        string line = string(num * 2, '-') + '\n';
        cout << line;

        // inside lines
        int r = 0, border = ( num - 1 ) * 2;
        string inside = string(border + 1, ' ') + "|\n";
        // top
        while ( r < border ) {
            inside[r] = '*';
            inside[border] = '*';
            r += 2;
            border -= 2;
            cout << inside;
        }
        // center line
        inside[r] = '*';
        cout << inside;
        // bottom
        while ( border > 0 ) {
            inside[r] = ' ';
            inside[border] = ' ';
            r += 2;
            border -= 2;
            cout << inside;
        }

        //bottom line
        cout << line;
```